# In Django-admin, how to show foreignkey's foreignkey in the same page?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-admin

I got a `Paper` and its foreignkey `ChoiceQuestion` model, and its foreignkey `Choices` model.

I'm wondering if django-admin show `Choices` in the change-form page of `Paper`.

```
class Paper(models.Model):
    """pagers"""
    # ...

class ChoiceQuestion(models.Model):
    paper = models.ForeignKey(Paper)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)


class Choice(models.Model):
    choice_question = models.ForeignKey(ChoiceQuestion)
    text = models.CharField(max_length=256)
```

normally we can edit `ChoiceQuestion` in `Paper`'s editing page, but how could I edit Choice in this page also?

Comment: you should be able to access by `__`, something like `paper__choicequestion__choices`

Comment: @Anzel could you tell me more about this , please

Comment: oh, thought you want to *access* the model. If you're talking about form, try [formsets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/forms/modelforms/#model-formsets)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe I did not describe clearly.

but [`djang-nested-inline`](https://github.com/s-block/django-nested-inline) helps a lot.

This allows we edit foreignkey's foreignkey in same page and nested for deep level.